# TypeScript Push via Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular

Hi I'm trying to push an item of mine onto my array. I currently have the array called freelist and I'm looking to push an item element:string onto my array. I have constructed the array and the constructor for my element and have used the array push function but it seems to push undefined to my array. Could you explain why the item is being pushed as an undefined or if it is even pushing the item at all?

```
 // My constructed items to push
contructor( stype:string, element:string)
{
  element = "test"
}

// My free list array
FreeList = [
  'Free Property static'
]

// My push function
freelistS(element,FreeList){
  this.FreeList.push(element);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `freelistS`? We need to see more of your code. Also, you misspelled `constructor`.

Comment: can you write also how you are using `freelistS`?

Comment: Looks like misspelling constructor was the problem. Didnt seem to pick that up thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea the way you call your `freelistS` method but the following should work:

```
contructor( stype:string, element:string)
{
  element = "test"
  this.freelistS(element, this.FreeList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seema like you are missing `this`

```
contructor( stype:string, element:string)
{
  this.element = "test"
}
```